# Invoke AWS Lambda into React page using aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js

I have this simple form executed into React page:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import {LambdaClient, InvokeCommand, LogType} from "@aws-sdk/client-lambda"; // ES Modules import

const FooterOne = ({ footerLight, style, footerGradient }) => {

  const invoke = async (funcName, payload) => {
    const client = new LambdaClient({});
    const command = new InvokeCommand({
      FunctionName: funcName,
      Payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
      LogType: LogType.Tail,
    });

    const { Payload, LogResult } = await client.send(command);
    const result = Buffer.from(Payload).toString();
    const logs = Buffer.from(LogResult, "base64").toString();
    return { logs, result };
  };
   

  return (
      <>
        <form>
          <input
              type='text'
              className='input-newsletter form-control me-2'
              placeholder='Enter your email'
              name='email'
              required=''
              autoComplete='off'
          />
          <input
              type='submit'
              value='Subscribe'
              data-wait='Please wait...'
          />
        </form>
      </>
  );
};

export default FooterOne;
```

Lambda code into AWS Lambda:

```
export const handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!'),
  };
  return response;
};
```

I created IAM user with the fallowing permissions:

[image]

Do you know how I can call the AWS Lambda code when I submit this simple form with JavaScript `aws-sdk`?

Comment: The web page can send the POST request to API Gateway which invokes the Lambda function. Your solution should ideally include authentication.

Comment: I don't want to use aws api gateway.

Comment: Take a look at [Lambda function URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html) but you will need to work out authentication and how to get AWS credentials securely, whichever solution you go with.

Comment: I can use `axios` or I have to use `aws-sdk-js` for  working with  Lambda function URL?

Comment: Depends on your choice of auth type. Read the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this, Hope it's working.**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { LambdaClient, InvokeCommand, LogType } from '@aws-sdk/client-lambda';

const FooterOne = ({ footerLight, style, footerGradient }) => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

  const invokeLambda = async (funcName, payload) => {
    try {
      const client = new LambdaClient({});
      const command = new InvokeCommand({
        FunctionName: funcName,
        Payload: JSON.stringify(payload),
        LogType: LogType.Tail,
      });

      const { Payload, LogResult } = await client.send(command);
      const result = Buffer.from(Payload).toString();
      const logs = Buffer.from(LogResult, 'base64').toString();
      return { logs, result };
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error invoking Lambda:', error);
      throw error;
    }
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const lambdaFunctionName = 'your-lambda-function-name';

      const payload = {
        email: email,
        // Include any other data you want to send to the Lambda function
      };

      const lambdaResponse = await invokeLambda(lambdaFunctionName, payload);
      console.log('Lambda invocation result:', lambdaResponse);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting form:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleEmailChange = (event) => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type='text'
          className='input-newsletter form-control me-2'
          placeholder='Enter your email'
          name='email'
          value={email}
          onChange={handleEmailChange}
          required=''
          autoComplete='off'
        />
        <input type='submit' value='Subscribe' data-wait='Please wait...' />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};

export default FooterOne;
```

**AWS Lambda Permissions**

- lambda:InvokeFunction: Allows invocation of a Lambda function.

**AWS IAM Permissions (for React App)**

- lambda:InvokeFunction: Allows invoking Lambda functions.

Comment: Thanks but I found this better solution: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/announcing-aws-lambda-function-urls-built-in-https-endpoints-for-single-function-microservices/

Comment: Can you show me how to make a request without `aws-sdk-js`. Looks like I don't need authentication.

Comment: You can use directly inside invokeLambda  

const lambdaEndpoint = 'https://your-lambda-endpoint.amazonaws.com'; // Replace with your Lambda endpoint

      const response = await fetch(lambdaEndpoint, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      });

Comment: Can you add a complete code example into the post, please?

Comment: - Removed aws-sdk-js imports: The code no longer imports any AWS SDK modules.
- Replaced invokeLambda feature: The preceding invokeLambda function the use of the SDK has been replaced with the model using fetch to invoke the characteristic URL.
- Updated handleSubmit feature:
- Uses the invokeLambda characteristic with the function URL.
- Includes instance error dealing with with an alert.

- Replace https://your-function-url with the actual URL of your Lambda function.
- Ensure your Lambda function is configured for unauthenticated access using a function URL.

Answer (score 1):

Listen for onSubmit Event on form by passing function to form tag like this

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
```

As you have added `type: submit` in your button, form submit event will be triggered on form when someone will click that button.

And you can write handleSubmit like this to invoke the lambda

```
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Validate and process the form data as needed
    const payload = { email: email }; // Customize this payload based on your Lambda function's requirements

    // Replace 'YourLambdaFunctionName' with the actual name of your Lambda function
    const { logs, result } = await invokeLambda('YourLambdaFunctionName', payload);

    // Handle the Lambda function response as needed
    console.log('Logs:', logs);
    console.log('Result:', result);
  };
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know what I need to configure on the AWS lambda panel in order this code to work?

Comment: Any idea what I need to configure on the AWS panel in order to invoke/use Lambda without API gateway?